# .htaccess - exclude directory from RewriteCond

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I have tried many rules and did well search to exclude a directory from the following rule in vain:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Currently this worked perfectly from my web app but I need now to exclude only one folder called "vendors"

Comment: Provide more details. What is your directory structure? What do you actually want to achieve? Where are you failing? Do you have access to server logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vendors/?$ [NC]
```

Which does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

What about next :

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/vendors !-d [NC]`

With this rule request that contains "vendors" will be processed,
if vendors not directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Rule :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vendors/.*$ [NC]`