# How to exclude a directory from .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a CRA app with a subdirectory where I have a CMS system. I need to redirect every request to the domain to index.html *except* `###.com/cms`, which needs to normally work to allow accessing the API.

I have .htaccess as such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/?$ [NC]`
 as per [.htaccess - exclude directory from RewriteCond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934748/htaccess-exclude-directory-from-rewritecond) but that didn't wotrk

Comment: Using this also didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Comment: To exclude you need to use a negitive condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/?$ [NC]` . You missed the `!` in your RewriteCond

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is:

Create .htaccess file in your cms directory

add only following line:

RewriteEngine Off